# What is "could not unlock signer account" error when sending tokens to an ERC20 token contract using transferFrom()?

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20

I'm using `testrpc -u 0 -u 1` to start the local testnet, deploying my [OpenZeppelin Standard Token](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/StandardToken.sol) smart contract with `truffle migrate`, and using web3 in my dapp.

As the user, I perform an action that calls `approve(myContractAddress, amount, {from: myAddress)`. Then I perform another action that calls `transferFrom(myAccount, myContractAddress, amount, {from: myContractAddress})` gives this error:

```
Error: could not unlock signer account
    at StateManager.queueTransaction 
(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:84996:21)
    at GethApiDouble.eth_sendTransaction 
(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:85804:14)
    at GethApiDouble.handleRequest (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-
testrpc/build/cli.node.js:85620:10)
    at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-
testrpc/build/cli.node.js:113129:18)
    at VmSubprovider.handleRequest (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-
testrpc/build/cli.node.js:113829:12)
    at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-
testrpc/build/cli.node.js:113129:18)
    at GethDefaults.handleRequest (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-
testrpc/build/cli.node.js:85935:12)
    at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-
testrpc/build/cli.node.js:113129:18)
    at FilterSubprovider.handleRequest 
(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:113388:7)
    at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:113129:18)
```

Essentially I want to have the contract transfer my funds to itself, on my behalf. It is almost working except for this error!

This would work:
`transferFrom(myAccount, someOtherAccount, amount, {from: someOtherAccount})`, but I need to be able to send to a contract.

Answer (score 3):

Contract accounts cannot be unlocked because they do not have a private key.

You cannot send a transaction on behalf of a contract. It has to be the contract making the call from Solidity. For example:

```
// In a method of your contract
function makeTransfer(address token, address myAccount, uint256 amount) public {
    ERC20(token).transferFrom(myAccount, address(this), amount);
}
```

Then you can call it from javascript with:

```
const tx = await myContract.makeTransfer(myToken.address, myAccount, amount);
```

Another possibility is to do a normal transfer to your contract address:

```
const tx = await myToken.transfer(myContractAddress, amount, {from: myAccount});
```

Comment: It is better if you ask a new question so it is easier to add your own details. In any case you cannot make a transfer on behalf of a contract.